# Jquery regresa valores vacios

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Tengo este código de jquery en el cual asigno los valores obtenidos en los txtVlr y txtCantidad a unas variables, para luego multilicarlos y el resultado ponerlo en el txtSubtotal justo cuando haya un cambio en el txtCantidad, pero al ejecutarlo las variables no obtienen el valor y finalmente no hay resultado.
El valor de txtVlr es obtenido al seleccionar un id en el txtidarticulo (No se si tenga algo que ver).
el valor de txtCantidad es digitado por el usuario.

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        var $Valor = $("#txtVlr").val();
        var $Cantidad = $("#txtCantidad").val();

        $("#txtCantidad").change(function(){
        $Subtotal = parseInt($Valor)*parseInt($Cantidad);
        alert ($Valor);
        alert ($Cantidad);


            $("#txtSubtotal").val($Subtotal); 
            alert ($Subtotal);
        });

    });  
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<div class="Container">
        <div class="margen">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">ID del Articulo</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <?php 
                    $CON = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","BDfactura") or die ("error");
                    $query="Select * From Articulo";
                    $sql = mysqli_query($CON, $query); 
                ?>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtidArticulo" type="text" list="Articulos">
                <datalist id="Articulos">
                       <?php 
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
                        ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['IdArticulo']; ?>"></option><?php } ?>

                </datalist>
                <?php mysqli_close($CON); ?>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Descripcion</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Valor Venta</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtVlr" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Cantidad</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtCantidad" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Subtotal</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtSubtotal" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btnlistar">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que intentas usar las variables fuera de su ámbito, o sea, las declaras fuera de la función `change` y cuando intentas usarlas dentro, no son conocidas en ese ámbito. En ese caso las puedes declarar dentro de la función donde vas a usarlas.

Así el código funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#txtCantidad").change(function() {
    var Valor = $("#txtVlr").val();
    var Cantidad = $("#txtCantidad").val();
    var Subtotal = parseInt(Valor) * parseInt(Cantidad);
    console.log(Valor);
    console.log(Cantidad);

    $("#txtSubtotal").val(Subtotal);
    console.log(Subtotal);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="Container">
    <div class="margen">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">ID del Articulo</label>
        <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
        <?php 
                    $CON = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","BDfactura") or die ("error");
                    $query="Select * From Articulo";
                    $sql = mysqli_query($CON, $query); 
                ?>
        <input class="form-control" id="txtidArticulo" type="text" list="Articulos">
        <datalist id="Articulos">
                       <?php 
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
                        ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['IdArticulo']; ?>"></option><?php } ?>

                </datalist>
        <?php mysqli_close($CON); ?>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">Descripcion</label>
        <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
        <input class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">Valor Venta</label>
        <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
        <input class="form-control" id="txtVlr" type="text" placeholder="valor">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">Cantidad</label>
        <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
        <input class="form-control" id="txtCantidad" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="ex1">Subtotal</label>
        <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
        <input class="form-control" id="txtSubtotal" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btnlistar">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

También, si lo prefieres,  puedes omitir el símbolo de `$` para declararlas. No se trata en sí de una variable de jQuery, sino de un valor. Entonces, mejor quitarle el símbolo. Generalmente `$` se usa para elementos a los cuales quieres aplicarles funcionalidades de jQuery, no para valores destinados a operaciones como cálculos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta fue de gran ayuda :3

Answer (score 1):

buenas dias yo lo haria de la siguiente forma,ya esta funcionado pero le quite el php

```
<head>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
        var $Valor = $("#txtVlr").val();
        var $Cantidad = $("#txtCantidad").val();
        $Subtotal = parseInt($Valor)*parseInt($Cantidad);
        alert ($Valor);
        alert ($Cantidad);
        alert ($Subtotal);
        $("#txtSubtotal").val($Subtotal); 
        //$('#fecha_mass').val($(this).data('fecha'));
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<div class="Container">
        <div class="margen">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">ID del Articulo</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->

                <input class="form-control" id="txtidArticulo" type="text" list="Articulos">
                <datalist id="Articulos">

                </datalist>


            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Descripcion</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Valor Venta</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtVlr" onchange="myFunction()" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Cantidad</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtCantidad" onchange="myFunction()" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <label for="ex1">Subtotal</label>
                <!-- DEBE TENER UN DDL PARA LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                <input class="form-control" id="txtSubtotal" type="text">
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="btnlistar">+</button>
            </div>
        -->
        </div>    
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
```